# No function remind of tensorflow show while using Pycharm and Anaconda in macOS

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, anaconda

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrPyC.png)

I`m new to`tensorflow` and got a little problems.

I have installed `tensorflow`(CPU only) using `conda` on Mac, it can work but without auto remind functions.

The error is such as:

> "cannot find reference'add' in module tensorflow". In this photo it
>   shows no function of tensorflow, but I still can use tensorflow.

Python3.5 + macOS High Sierra + pycharm 2016.2 + anaconda

Comment: What python interpreter is configured?

Comment: Anaconda python3.5. I have solve this problem by reinstall it.